# WSO2 implement only HTTP service

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, ibm-api-management

How to publish only Http service from WSO2AM?
I am receiving an empty response from the server when I access WSO2AM service from my client.

This is what I am setting for HTTP. 
Service is working using HTTPS but that is not desired.

[image]

Comment: Your configuration is correct. What is the client you use? What is the status code of the response?

Comment: I tested it on ARC, Rest Console, CURL on MAC Terminal, and in my code. All gave same empty response from server. I didn't check the status code.

Comment: Please enable wire logs in apim, send a request again, and post your logs.
http://lakshanigamage.blogspot.com/2015/03/how-to-enable-wire-logs-in-wso2-esbapim.html